# Bottom Overflowed By Infinity Pixels Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

I added an Navigation bar to the bottom of the app and discovered the error. I tried wrapping a bunch of widgets with `scroll view` `mainaxisalignment`, `expanded` and tried different methods that i saw on youtube or on Stack Overflow [Overflowed by Infinity Pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLD7M.png)
The code for the Home page and navigation bar:

```
import 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:ride/controllers/task_controller.dart';
import 'package:ride/services/theme_services.dart';
import 'package:ride/ui/add_task_bar.dart';
import 'package:ride/ui/theme.dart';
import 'package:ride/ui/widgets/button.dart';
import 'package:ride/ui/widgets/task_tile.dart';
import '../models/task.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    AddTaskPage(),
  ];
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  final _taskController = Get.put(TaskController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appbar(),
      backgroundColor: context.theme.colorScheme.background,
      body:
      Column(children: [
        _addTaskBar(),
        _addDateBar(),
        _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        _showTasks(),
      ]),
    );
  }

  _showTasks() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Obx(() {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _taskController.taskList.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              Task task = _taskController.taskList[index];
              //print(task.toJson());
              if (task.date == DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate)) {
                return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                    position: index,
                    child: SlideAnimation(
                        child: FadeInAnimation(
                            child: Row(
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            _showBottomSheet(context, task);
                          },
                          child: TaskTile(task),
                        )
                      ],
                    ))));
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            });
      }),
    );
  }

  _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Task task) {
    Get.bottomSheet(
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
        height: task.isCompleted == 1
            ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.24
            : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.32,
        color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.grey[850] : Colors.white,
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
            height: 6,
            width: 120,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Colors.grey[600]),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          task.isCompleted == 1
              ? Container()
              : _bottomSheetButton(
                  label: "Join",
                  onTap: () {
                    _taskController.markTaskCompleted(task.id!);

                    Get.back();
                  },
                  clr: primaryClr,
                  context: context),
          _bottomSheetButton(
              label: "Delete",
              onTap: () {
                _taskController.delete(task);
                Get.back();
              },
              clr: Colors.red[400]!,
              context: context),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          _bottomSheetButton(
              label: "Close",
              onTap: () {
                Get.back();
              },
              clr: Colors.red[400]!,
              isClose: true,
              context: context),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  _bottomSheetButton({
    required String label,
    required Function()? onTap,
    required Color clr,
    bool isClose = false,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
        height: 55,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
              width: 2,
              color: isClose == true
                  ? Get.isDarkMode
                      ? Colors.grey[600]!
                      : Colors.grey[400]!
                  : clr),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: isClose == true ? Colors.transparent : clr,
        ),
        child: Center(
            child: Text(
          label,
          style:
              isClose ? titleStyle : titleStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }

  _addDateBar() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 20,
        left: 20,
      ),
      child: DatePicker(
        DateTime.now(),
        height: 100,
        width: 80,
        initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
        selectionColor: primaryClr,
        selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
        dateTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        dayTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        monthTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
          textStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        onDateChange: (date) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedDate = date;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _addTaskBar() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
                  style: subHeadingStyle,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Today',
                  style: headingStyle,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          MyButton(
              label: "+ Add",
              onTap: () async {
                await Get.to(const AddTaskPage());
                _taskController.getTasks();
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _appbar() {
    return AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: context.theme.colorScheme.background,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            ThemeService().switchTheme();
          },
          child: Icon(
              Get.isDarkMode
                  ? Icons.wb_sunny_outlined
                  : Icons.dark_mode_outlined,
              size: 30,
              color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
        ),
        actions: [
          Icon(Icons.person_outline,
              size: 30, color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          )
        ]);
  }
}
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';
import 'package:ride/login/login.dart';
import 'package:ride/services/theme_services.dart';
import 'package:ride/ui/home_page.dart';
import 'package:ride/ui/theme.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp(isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isLoggedIn;
  const MyApp({super.key, required this.isLoggedIn});

  //Root of Application
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: Themes.light,
        darkTheme: Themes.dark,
        themeMode: ThemeService().theme,
        home: isLoggedIn ? const HomePage() : LogIn());
  }
}
```

I tried Wrapping the `Container` and `SafeArea` widgets in the `Expanded` widget and tried wrapping the same widgets with `SingleChildScrollView` AND wrapped the 2 widgets with `Expanded` AND `SingleChildScrollView` but nothing worked.

Comment: From the current snippet, I've failed to reproduce the error

Comment: I gave more context hope that helps!

Comment: Actually your body elements are hidden, like `_addTaskBar` and other things, it would be better if you could include sample full snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: i added EVEN more infromation, I removed the navigation bar becuase i was getting an error still when i removed it @YeasinSheikh

Comment: sorry man, I am not sure, you can comment widget on scaffold's body one by one and then check inner widget at the same way.

Comment: I fixed it!! I removed `_widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex)` and all errors are gone @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!! I removed `_widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex)` and all errors are gone.